# Why can I interpret a log transformed dependent variable in terms of percent change in linear regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, logarithm, percentage, transform

Looking at resources such as [this one](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-interpret-log-transformed-variables-in-terms-of-percent-change-in-linear-regression/) and [this one](https://data.library.virginia.edu/interpreting-log-transformations-in-a-linear-model/#:%7E:text=Only%20the%20dependent%2Fresponse%20variable,increase%20in%20the%20independent%20variable.), you see claims like

> "Exponentiate the coefficient, subtract one from this number, and
> multiply by 100. This gives the percent increase (or decrease) in the
> response for every one-unit increase in the independent variable.
> Example: the coefficient is 0.198. (exp(0.198) – 1) * 100 = 21.9. For
> every one-unit increase in the independent variable, our dependent
> variable increases by about 22%".

This formula for converting coefficients into percent changes seems to have come out of nowhere. I cannot see why this computes a percent change.

Consider [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor-and-or-response), and the top answer just states the following result which appears to compute the same thing in a different way:

> ```
> log(DV) = Intercept + B1 * IV + Error
> ```
>
> "One unit increase in IV is associated with a (B1 * 100) percent
> increase in DV."

Furthermore, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106278/interpreting-log-transformed-percentages-in-ols) has an answer that says

> "keep in mind that the interpretation of a "unit change in a
> logarithm" as a "percent change" is a local approximation."

This just confuses me more. Why do these formulas only produce an approximation?

All of this leads to the question... Why can I interpret a log transformed dependent variable in terms of percent change in linear regression? (And why is it only an approximation?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say we have a model like this:

$$\log\hat y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x$$

Since $\exp$ is the inverse function of $\log$, we can do this:

$$\hat y = f(x)=\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)$$

Now, what happens when $x$ grows by 1? $f(x)$ multiplies by $\exp(\beta_1)$:

$$\begin{align}
f(x+1)&=\exp[\beta_0+\beta_1(x+1)]\\
&=\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)\cdot\exp(\beta_1)\\
&=f(x)\cdot\exp(\beta_1)
\end{align}$$

OK, now how much does $f(x)$ grow *in percentages*?

$$\left(\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}-1\right)\cdot100=(\exp(\beta_1)-1)\cdot100$$

This explains that formula for converting coefficients into percent changes. Until here, we used no approximations. Now, if $x$ is a small enough number, we can approximate $\exp(x)\approx1+x$. This approximation is called a first order Taylor expansion of $\exp(x)$ around $x=0$. If you replace this approximation on the $\text{coefficients}\rightarrow\text{percent change}$ we found earlier, you get:

$$\text{percent change}\approx100\cdot\beta_1$$

So, when $\beta_1$ is a small number, you can interpret it directly as a percent change - but keep in mind that this is just an approximation.